# Mysql database didn't connect through sqlyog or any other mysql software?

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2

I can connect to a MySQL server through a browser and also I can show all database list through PuTTY. But when I try to use `sqlyog` or running the `mysqldump` command through PuTTY it shows this error:

> ERROR NO:2003 cannot connect to mysql server on "****"

How I give these tools permission?

I use this command

```
mysqldump -h "1st IP Address" -u username -ppasswprd DB Name | mysql -h "2nd IP Address" -u username -ppasswprd DB Name
```

I get that ERROR

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1130: Host '2nd IP Address' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server when trying to connect
```

Comment: The number in parentheses at the end of the error (not included in your question) is critical for understanding the specific reason why you can't connect. It may not be "permission" related.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared the command (with ip/pass redacted)

Comment: Please check I edited my question

Comment: Your user has the access granted for the database?
grant all priviliges on *.DBNAME to user@2ndipaddress identified by "password" ?

Comment: I already tried that but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to GRANT access to the database

GRANT priva on database.* to user@ip

for example

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE on mydb.* to fred@10.10.5.5

You can also add IDENTIFIED BY 'password'

if you want to also add a password for the user in the same step. Obviously this is performed on the database on "1st ip address" giving "2dn ip address" after the @.

Comment: Or maybe vice-versa, now that you edit the question. :)

Comment: GRANT privilege didnot accept by AMAZON RDS. GRANT privilege is only accepted on root user